# Symfony2 and Assetic - cssrewrite works perfectly for dev, not for prod

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I include my CSS with the following code:

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/majorproductionssewingdivasite/css/*.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

In dev, this allows me to use image sprites without any problems.  The resulting URL to my sprite is:

`http://localhost/diva/web/bundles/majorproductionssewingdivasite/images/diva-sprites.jpg`

But, in prod, it gets mapped to:

`http://localhost/diva/bundles/majorproductionssewingdivasite/images/diva-sprites.jpg`

Notice the lack of web directory.

The generated code in the CSS file is as it should be, and all my CSS (both the dev 'chunks' and the finalized prod assetic dump) are at `web/css/`.  Any ideas as to why the prod environment is skipping the web directory?

EDIT: what's weird is that both dev and prod generate the same URL in the CSS itself:

`url('../../bundles/majorproductionssewingdivasite/images/diva-sprites.jpg')`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solution is to dump the assets in the prod environment:

```
$ app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  But you may need to clear the cache first too `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`. Dumping the asset files before cleaning the cache didn't resolve the problem for me. I'm a bit new to Symfony2, but from what I've just experienced, it seems to dump the asset files from the cache, not from the physical files.

Comment: OMG how i can miss this @_@

Answer (score 9):

Remember to **Clear the Cache**

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

berore

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

Answer (score 2):

Also remember to appropriate configure assetic, in your config_prod.yml set as below:

```
assetic:
    use_controller: false
```

---

Edit:
As said in [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment) (actually in chapter refers to dev environment): *tell Symfony to stop trying to process these files dynamically*

Comment: Please include some extra details in order to make your reply complete

Comment: You are right, but usual configuration is already `use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'`

Answer (score 0):

In debug mode, Assetic 1.1 also seems to rewrite CSS even when it's not in the {% stylesheets %} tag. So it's worth checking that's there when you turn off debug in production.