# Symfony2 assetic cssrewrite with mod_rewrite on app.php giving incorrect basepath

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite, assetic

When using cssrewrite I am getting the incorrect paths. It works fine when using the app_dev.php or app.php in the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator), for example, `mysite.com/site/app.php/login` will correctly function. However, using `mysite.com/site/login` will not work.

When viewing the CSS files I see the following while accessing `mysite.com/site/app.php/login`:

```
 src: url('../../bundles/acmetest/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1')
```

The correct path when viewing mysite.com/site/login should be:

```
 src: url('../bundles/acmetest/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1')
```

Here is my htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Is there a way to configure the production environment to know that its path is `/`, not `app.php/` so that it correctly configures the cssrewrite paths?

Here is my Twig configuration for assetic:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets
        'bundles/acmetest/css/bootstrap.min.css'
        'bundles/acmetest/css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css'
        'bundles/acmetest/css/jquery.iphone.toggle.css'
        'bundles/acmetest/css/font-awesome.css'
        'bundles/acmetest/css/glyphicons.css'
        'bundles/acmetest/css/halflings.css'
        'bundles/acmetest/css/retina.min.css'
        'bundles/acmetest/css/style.css'
    filter='cssrewrite'
    %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: do you have `use_controller` set to `true` in production?! how did you install/symlink/dump your assets? `assets:install web` ? with/without `--symlink` ? with `--env=prod` ? where/how do you configure your asset collection to use the cssrewrite filer - `twig` template? `assetic.assets` configuration?

Comment: use_controller: false in production assets:install web --symlink for install

I have updated my original post with my twig template configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Before you proceed - read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500573/path-of-assets-in-css-files-in-symfony2) carefully ...

---

There are actually two possible causes that come to my mind right now.

At first - the cssrewrite filter does not work with the `@Bundle`-syntax. ([documentation reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-css-stylesheets))

You have to include your stylesheets like this in a twig template:

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/my/css/style.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Further in order to dump your assets for production use ...

```
 app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

... to make sure they are being dumped with the right environment settings. ( [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073117/symfony2-and-assetic-cssrewrite-works-perfectly-for-dev-not-for-prod) )

Comment: Yes and this works just fine. However once I use mod_rewrite to hide app.php (using e.g.: www.mysite.com/test/login vs www.mysite.com/test/app.php/login) it no longer works. It is re-writing basing off the app.php being part of the URI. Even though it is not being used in production. This is both the same for production & development environments. They both work fine until I use mod-rewrite to hide the application path.

Comment: edited my answer with another hint to the probably best answer on stackoverflow regarding this topic.